# Using map on NSDictionary

Tags: swift, closures, nsdictionary

**SETUP**

- I am loading data from my server by using my API
- The returned data is in JSON
- The JSON provided by the API is pictured below
- I use ALAMOFIRE to receive the data from the API and parse the JSON response

**JSON**

```
{
data: [
{
owner: "FREDL",
street: "Apothekergasse 1",
latitude: "48.261900",
longitude: "11.445200"
}
],
meta: "Testmeta"
}
```

**AED CLASS**

```
class AED: NSObject {
    let owner: String
    let street: String
    let mapType: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D


    init(owner: String, street: String, mapType: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.owner = owner
        self.street = street
        self.mapType = mapType
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        super.init()
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to use the `map` function on result items to create an `AED` object for each result provided by the API.

```
func getAvailableAEDsInRange(#latitude: Float, longitude: Float) {
    Alamofire.request(MFNetworkController.Router.getAEDInRange(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)).responseJSON() {
        (_, _, JSON, error) in
        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                let aedInfo = ((JSON as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as! [NSDictionary])
                aedInfo.map() {
                 (...)   
                }
                println(aedInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

`Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`

**QUESTIONS**

1. As I am providing a Dictionary of results and I access the argument by `$0["owner"]` , why should this error message appear?
2. When I use for example `println($0["owner"]` I get a result and the error disappears. Why is the access then possible?

**UPDATE**

I changed the Problem Function as seen above. When I split up the code into:

`let aedInfo = ((JSON as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as! [NSDictionary])`

and

`aedInfo.map() {}`

Then I already get the error message:
`Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`

The Output of aedInfo is:

```
[{
    latitude = "48.261900";
    longitude = "11.445200";
    owner = FREDL;
    street = "Apothekergasse 1";
}]
```

Which is the Array of Dictionaries as I expected. But why does the map function return the error?

**UPDATE 2**

I found an example on Ray Wenderlich and he is taking the same approach. But there is no error. Where is the difference then?

// 3
  Alamofire.request(Five100px.Router.PopularPhotos(self.currentPage)).responseJSON() {
    (_, _, JSON, error) in

```
if error == nil {
  // 4
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    // 5, 6, 7
    let photoInfos = ((JSON as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("photos") as! [NSDictionary]).filter({ ($0["nsfw"] as! Bool) == false }).map { PhotoInfo(id: $0["id"] as! Int, url: $0["image_url"] as! String) }

    // 8
    let lastItem = self.photos.count
    // 9
    self.photos.addObjectsFromArray(photoInfos)

    // 10
    let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.photos.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }

    // 11
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
    }

    self.currentPage++
  }
}
self.populatingPhotos = false
```

}
}

Comment: You cant use map on a dictionary but I thinl you can on dictionari property 'values'

Comment: But I think I use this on the values property. by using "valueForKey"?

Comment: 'CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) as! Float' ?

Comment: Thank you. THAT is a mistake for sure as well.... But this is not connected to the other problem I think?

Comment: I am working with `Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)`

Comment: Try and see if it disappears.

Comment: "AED" as! String is not necessery and I think it will cause an error aswell.

Comment: I deleted the content inside the map closure completely (see Update) but the error is still there. So it is not the content inside the closure that is responsible as it seems

Comment: You have to return something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81087/discussion-between-arbitur-and-sesc360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode cannot be trusted with its reasons for an error in Swift, but you can trust it points it out in the right location :)

`CLLocationCoordinate2dMake() as! Float` will create an error. Because you cannot cast a struct to a number.

Remove `as! Float` and your error will go away.